# IPN not passing variable

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

Im trying to pass a custom variable trought paypal button and get the value back with the ipn, im using this hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo"".$username.""; ?>">
```

This is my full button :

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" style="margin-left:32px;" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo"".$settings['admin']['paypal'].""; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="PT">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="account">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo"".$username.""; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo"".$item_catch['price']."";?>">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

And this is my ipn listener :

```
<?php

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);


if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

// PAYMENT VALIDATED & VERIFIED!



$username = $_POST['custom'];



$add = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO purchases(fromm) VALUES(?)");
$add->bind_param("s", $username);
$add->execute();
$add->close(); 


}

else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {

// PAYMENT INVALID & INVESTIGATE MANUALY!



}
}
fclose ($fp);
}
```

the problem is that im not getting the custom variable back and it keeps inserting into database null on fromm

Comment: Have you checked the HTML source code as appears in your browser, to check the value is being added to the form correctly?

Comment: I did and it is added correctly

Comment: you don't need to do <?php echo"".$username.""; ?> simply <?php echo $username; ?> would work but that's not the issue.

Comment: See if this helps you 
:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355387/grabbing-a-custom-field-with-paypal-ipn-in-php

Comment: you able to var_dump($username) to see what it should be before you post it ?

Comment: @OliverBS as well, they could just do: `<?= $username; ?>`

Comment: im not , ipn is not returned to user

Comment: you could easily change the action and test what is being sent.

Comment: Is the column name really `fromm` and not `from`?

Comment: Whats the value of `$username` after `$username = $_POST['custom'];`?

Answer (score 0):

You have too many quotes:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
```